# Having trouble with CouchDB design document and validate_doc_update function

Tags: json, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB, and I'm having a lot of trouble with getting my design document to work in my database.

This is my design document:

```
{
"language": "javascript",

"validate_doc_update": "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) {
    function require(field, message) {
        message = message || "Document must have a " + field;
        if (!newDoc[field]) throw({forbidden : message});
    };
    function unchanged(field) {
        if (oldDoc && toJSON(oldDoc[field] != toJSON(newDoc[field])) {
        }
    };

    if (newDoc.type == "fortune") {
        require("body");
        require("sequence_id");
        require("created_at");
        unchanged("sequence_id");
        unchanged("created_at");
    }
};",

"views": { 
    "fortune_count": {
        "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.sequence_id && doc.body) { emit(doc.sequence_id, doc.body); }",
        "reduce": "_count"
        }
},

"shows": {
}
}
```

Let me break down the problems I'm having:

1. I'm having trouble sending this to my database as a put request. 
   Apparently this is invalid JSON.  I'm not an expert at JSON, and
   this extremely frustrating.  Any thoughts?
2. Because of the problems I was having with the put request, I decided
   to add my design document using Futon.  My database seems to be fine
   with the view I have here, but when I try to add documents to the
   database, I get an error saying that my validate_doc_update text
   doesn't evaluate to a function.  Any advice on what is wrong with my
   validate function?

Because of the difficulty I'm having with my validate function, I tried putting a dumb version in the design doc:

```
"validate_doc_update": "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) { if (newDoc.type == "fortune") {} };",
```

I can create documents with this version in place, but it is not of much use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul Nichols

Comment: I'm positive someone else is going to have a better answer, but I've experienced similar problems with putting design documents in.  I use http://jsonlint.com/ quite a bit to clean up my json and to validate it.  Pasting in your design document points to the third line.  I had the exact same problem and wrote a script to remove tabs and carriage returns from my json text.  I was able to insert it then!  Hahaha.  Also when uploading the documents with PUT, I had a byte order marker in my file that made it invalid. Removed the first three bytes and it was fine.

Comment: You have `"` inside your function body that is breaking the JSON. You need to escape the ones inside `require(...)` and `unchanged(...)`. ie: `require(\"body\");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just forgot to close bracket in `(oldDoc && toJSON(oldDoc[field] != toJSON(newDoc[field]))`